# Pulling only one piece of data with an Excel web query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a bunch of data in the format:

```
somedata,otherdata,dataparameter
```

in an Excel spreadsheet.

Dataparameter combines with a URL to get me to a page that has a piece of data I want to suck into my spreadsheet.

As it stands right now, I have a .IQY file set up that uses dataparameter to go out and fetch data from the webpage and insert it into the spreadsheet.  Unfortunately, the page consists of half a dozen key-value pairs, and I only want one of those values.

```
KEY1 value1
KEY2 value2
KEY3 value3
KEY4 value4
```

All I care about is value3.  Is there a way to mangle the .IQY file so that it gets only one value from the page, or one key/value pair, rather than the entire table?  The problem I'm having is that every query inserts data down several rows, and I have 1000 rows of data that I need to do this with.  In my dream world, I wind up with a row that looks like:

```
somedata,otherdata,dataparameter,value3
```

Unfortunately, my web search skills have not turned up good documentation on the nitty gritty of .iqy files.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the web page is setup so that each of the key/value pairs is its own table, then you can't do it through and IQY file.

One option is to put the web query on another (possibly hidden) sheet and use a formula (possibly OFFSET and the named range that's created with the query) to retrieve the third value.